# Related type for the arguments of template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

How can I tell the compiler that `U` is equivalent to either `std::vector<T>` or `T`?

```
template<typename T, typename U> std::vector<T> foo(T t, U){return std::vector<T>{};}
```

Comment: The return type of this example `t` of type `T` doesn't match the function return type of `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: @Amro Updated,now.

Comment: Why would you need to? `U` is not used and can be anything.

Comment: @n.m. The code snippet in the question is just a demo. I want to tell the compiler that `U` only could be `std::vector<T>` or `T`. But I don't know how to achieve this goal. Sorry for my poor English. See the code snippet in my answer to better understand my goal.'

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is better or worse than your proposed solution, but you can try <s>[template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization), which is similar to function overloading</s> function overloading.
This would look like this

```
// Generic function
// UPDATE: you can ignore this function altogether and use the two overloads below
template<typename T, typename U> std::vector<T> foo(T t, U u) { // Do something}

// First specialization for the case of U == T
// UPDATE: this is an *overload*, not a specialization
template<typename T> std::vector<T> foo(T t, T u) { // Do something}

// Second specialization for the case of U == std::vector<T>
// UPDATE: this is an *overload*, not a specialization
template<typename T> std::vector<T> foo(T t, std::vector<T> u) { // Do something}
```

A possible downside of this approach is the possibility of repeating code, which violates the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.
As such, if your objective is to simply constraint your arguments without needing to change the function definition, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74555193/15749309) may be better suited for such application.

**Update**: As [@HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat) commented, my example was of overloading, and not of template specialization. I updated the text accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This solution works indeed. But it causes the wrong expression(say `foo(int, double)`) compiles. How do you think about it?

Comment: You could specify the declaration of the base function *without* defining it (i.e. just use `templaet<typename T, typename U> std::vector<T> foo(T t, U u);`. This way, `foo<int, double>(1, 1.5)` would *not* compile and you'd get a compile error. The other specializations would still work (i.e., compile and run).

Comment: Those are overloads, not specializations.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `template<typename T> std::vector<T> foo(T t, T u)` and `template<typename T> std::vector<T> foo(T t, std::vector<T> u) ` is the partial specializations for `template<typename T, typename U> std::vector<T> foo(T t, U u)`. Why you say ***Those are overloads, not specializations***? Could you please explain that in detail for me?

Comment: A specialization would have `<...>` after the function name, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

I would disable type deduction (by using depending type) on second argument and provided two overloads.

```cpp
namespace me {
   // c++20 has this, so putting that in own namespace to cover older standards
   template<typename T>
   strut identity {
       using type = T;
   };

   template<typename T>
   using identity_t = typename identityT<>::type;
}


template<typename T>
std::vector<T> foo(T t, const std::vector<me::indentity_t<T>>& v) {
   auto copy = v;
   copy.push_back(t);
   return copy;
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> foo(T t, me::indentity_t<T> v) {
   return { v, t };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself.

It seems could be achieved by `std::enable_if`. **Is there any better way?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
template<typename T, typename U, typename = typename std::enable_if< 
          std::is_same< T, U >::value || std::is_same<std::vector<T>, U>::value>::type>
std::vector<int> foo()
{
    std::cout << "on the move!\n";

    return {};
}

int main()
{
    foo<int, int>();
    foo<int, std::vector<int>>();
    //foo<int, float>();  //does not compile, in expectation.
}
```

[A better/harder example](https://godbolt.org/z/6nhrK85oa):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
 
template<typename T, typename U, typename = typename std::enable_if< 
          std::is_same< T, U >::value || std::is_same<std::vector<T>, U>::value>::type>
void foo(std::function<U(void)> func)
{
    std::cout << "on the move!\n";
}

int main()
{
    foo<int>(std::function<int(void)>());
    foo<int>(std::function<std::vector<int>(void)>());
    //foo<int>(std::function<float(void)>());  //does not compile, in expectation.
}
```

Comment: Are you really limited to C++11? With each version after that there were small improvements that make this a bit simpler.

Comment: Something you might want to be aware when using `enable_if`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#Notes (Not necessarily in effect based on what you have so far)

Comment: @user17732522 My project is limited to use `C++11` feature.  Other standards are welcome, too. I want to learn more.

Comment: @John With C++20 is is much simpler. You just write `requires std::same_as< T, U > || std::same_as<std::vector<T>, U>` below the template head or the function head.

Comment: @user17732522 What a nice, beautiful code!